# How to get which activity is running android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, testing

I`m trying to check the flow of my program and to do so I need a way to get the type of a class that is currently running.

I tried searching the web for some info about the subject but as I see most of the examples add a static variable for the active data.

Beside testing the logic of my program I want to test the `GUI` as well so I will be able to check that after I press a button the correct activity is running.

There isn't much info about testing on Android studio so any help will be highly appreciated (Such as "*You are in a completely wrong path, you can test your GUI by...*")

Thanks

Comment: You can use "current activity" app,it is available in play store. It will show the name of a  current activity class. Here is the link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.willme.topactivity&hl=en

Comment: dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedActivity

Comment: You can debug your app using `Log` class in Android Studio. Here you can see what functions are called and what activity is opened, if you have done your log correctly

Comment: @Arjun can I use the current activity app to get the class in an automated testing suit? I want to build a testing framework to run all the test automatically.

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov Thanks i will try this if all other options fail, i'm trying to make it as clean as possible and in this way I test the state of the logger while i`m tring to test the flow of my program

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface for this approach.

First step is implement Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to your **Application** class.

```
class MyApplication extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {...}
```

Second step is just register for `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` callbacks in your MyApplication.class's `onCreate` method

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }
```

Last step is just override the methods from **Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** in **MyApplication** class

```
void onActivityCreated(Activity var1, Bundle var2);

void onActivityStarted(Activity var1);

void onActivityResumed(Activity var1);

void onActivityPaused(Activity var1);

void onActivityStopped(Activity var1);

void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity var1, Bundle var2);

void onActivityDestroyed(Activity var1);
```

Now you can easily know which activity is currently running :) Happy coding!

Comment: I Highly appreciate your detailed answer, now in those methods Should i log the events and check the logger using regex? There is no way to get the current activity class that is running? just after the activity has logged the relevant data i should scan the logger?

Comment: these methods returns you the activity classes itselfs directly. I really can not understand what do you mean ? You can log or create a logic or whatever you want with these methods.